# React Transition group not firing

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

i tried to create a simple transition with react transition group, but i can't get it to work- transitions aren't working.
i did used a unique key.

for the example i just did a simple 2 image fade in fade out component:

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.TransitionGroup;

var Image = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () { 

        return ({imglink: 'http://belaumi.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/3D-Animated-Frog-Image.jpg', status: 1})
    },

    update: function () {

        console.log(this);
        if (this.state.status==1)
        {
            this.setState({ imglink: 'http://www.codefuture.co.uk/projects/imagehost/demo/di/KXY1/Image-b%C3%A9b%C3%A9-facebook-8.jpg', status:2})

        } else {

            this.setState({ imglink: 'http://belaumi.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/3D-Animated-Frog-Image.jpg', status:1})
        }
    } , 

    render: function ()  {

        return (
      <div>
          <div className='container'>
          <button onClick={this.update.bind(this)}>Click</button>
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example">
          <img key={this.state.status} src={this.state.imglink}/>
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
    });

    React.render(
        <div>
            <Image/>
        </div>,
        document.getElementById('reactbody')
    )

</script>
```

i've also included proper css:

```
.example-enter {
    opacity: 0.01;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
.example-enter.example-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
.example-leave.example-leave-active {
    opacity: 0.01;
}
```

any idea why this is not working? the image does switch, but no fade..

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The addons name is CSSTransitionGroup:

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
```

instead of

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.TransitionGroup;
```

(Notice the **CSS**TransitionGroup)

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wvt30ocx/